# GLPK: access to data array with variable length

Tags: glpk

```
set ORIG;
set DEST;
set LINKS within {ORIG,DEST};

printf {i in ORIG, j in DEST} "LINKS[%s,%s] = %g \n",i,j,LINKS[i][j];

data;

set ORIG := GARY CLEV PITT;
set DEST := FRA DET LAN WIN STL FRE LAF;

set LINKS := 
   (GARY,*) DET LAN STL LAF
   (CLEV,*) FRA DET LAN WIN STL LAF
   (PITT,*) FRA WIN STL FRE;

end;
```

This stops with this error message:

> LINKS cannot be subscripted

How can I define `LINKS` so that it can be accessed with `LINKS[i][j]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some advice from gnu-help, this seems to be a better syntax
for this problem:

```
set ORIG;
set DEST;

param LINKS{ORIG, DEST} default 0;

for {i in ORIG, j in DEST} printf "LINKS[%s,%s] = %g \n",i,j,LINKS[i,j];

data;

set ORIG := GARY CLEV PITT;
set DEST := FRA DET LAN WIN STL FRE LAF;


param LINKS : FRA DET LAN WIN STL FRE LAF :=
     GARY   1 2 3 4 5 6 .
     CLEV   . 2 . 4 . 6 .
     PITT   1 2 3 4 5 6 7;
end;
```